# How to validate the user input is in a certain range?

Tags: java, loops, validation, dice

I wrote a program that asks the person for strings of numbers between 1-6 and returns the number of rolls it took to get the string. I want to validate the input so that the person doesn't enter a number bigger than 6 or smaller than 1 and I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

```
int SIDES = 6;
String userString = "null";
String answer = "null";
int length = 0;
do {
    do {
        System.out.print("please enter a string of 6 numbers you want to be rolled");
        userString = keyboard.next();
    while (length != SIDES) {
        System.out.println("please enter a valid string number");
        userString = keyboard.next();
    } 
        length = userString.length();
} while ( length != SIDES); // I want to add the validation to this line
dieRoll(userString);
```

Comment: Perhaps if you tell us what it is you think is going wrong, and what it is you have tried you might get more positive responses.  Have you tried to do a search (here and google) as to how to limit user input in Java?

Comment: i tried taking users input one number at a time and making sure it fits but i feel like this is not practical. i tried but didnt find an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
while (length != SIDES) {
    userString = keyboard.next();
    try {
        int userStringNumber = Integer.parseInt(userString);
        if(userStringNumber<1||userStringNumber>6)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please provide a number");
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
        System.out.println("Number should be between 1 and 6");
    }

}
```

Comment: this doesnt work because it turns the whole string to a single number

Comment: I don't understand the logic you want. i just give you a way to validate string is a number and between 1 and 6.

Comment: If you want a single character from the string use  charAt